# ExceptionHandler can't catch response exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm create a web api application on dotnet core try to catch an exception but it's not work

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public long Num { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }
        public decimal Avg => Math.Round(TotalCost / Num, 4);
    }
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<TestModel> Get()
        {
            return new TestModel { Num = 0, TotalCost = 1 };
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output of an exception ,But it shows nomal

Comment: Hi, You are not trying to catch any exception :)  where is your `try` and `catch`?

Comment: in startup i use a ErrorHandling middleware,but the request pipeline is not the scope where this error occurs

Answer (score 2):

It won't raise an exception until you call .Avg: `_ = l.Avg;` so the actual code is triggered and will throw a `DivideByZeroException` exception.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<TestModel> Get()
    {

        var l =  new TestModel { Num = 0, TotalCost = 1 };
        _ = l.Avg;

        return l;
    }
```

Comment: but in complex projects, we can't do this. This exception occurs on the return rather than on the action

Comment: But that is ok, this is for testing purposes only isn't it? I thought you just wanted to test your ErrorHandling middleware.